# Service remoting / sender - receiver

Tags: c#, microservices, listener, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I would like my stateless service (**sender**) sends an object to a stateful one (**receiver**) by service remoting.
I only find the way that statefull service (**receiver**) creates a proxy and waits for a message from sender.

```
ISenderService senderClient = ServiceProxy.Create<ISenderService>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/SenderService"));

string message = await senderClient.MessageAsync();
```

It is not that I want. I want stateless service (**sender**) creates proxy to the stateful one, sends messages, and stateful one (**receiver**) listens and do something when it receives a message.

How can I do that ? I didn't find any documentations or examples about this case.

**EDIT:**

If I well understood, service A (stateless) creates proxy to call service B (stateful) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

1. Determine the partitionkey of the partition you want to interact with.
2. Create a service proxy using that info
3. Call the service

```
long partitionKey = DeterminePartitionAddressFromContext();
var proxy = _serviceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<ISenderService>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/SenderService"), new ServicePartitionKey(partitionKey), TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica, RemotingListenerName);
await proxy.MessageAsync();
```

More info in [this example](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/blob/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.IndexService/IndexService.cs), in which a stateless service calls a stateful service using SF remoting.

The partition in the example is based by using a [hash](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/blob/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.IndexService/HashingHelper.cs) of the input object, which will return an int64 number, which can be used to address an Int64RangePartition. You can likely do a similar thing in your stateful service.
See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN9zQm_FVVw) for more info on the example and partitioning strategies.

Comment: Thanks. This example helps me a lot. How can I retrieve partitionKey ?

Comment: I've added more info to the answer.